# Text-align :center not working even after setting display:block

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to center the form contents .But its not working even after setting display:block for the container of form and then applying text-align:center;I did another work around put padding:0 33% it centered the form contents but with different view port sizes it would shrink the text box size .I want to center the form elements and want them to occupy the container size and please explain why this is happenning and what is that I have overlooked .I want it to able work for all view port sizes .**I want to know the reason causing this which overrides even inline code**

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JXLLvV)

**CSS**

```
 #Banner{
         background:url('http://i67.tinypic.com/midkki.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
         width:100%;
         min-height:960px;


         }
         #Menu{
          min-height:120px;

         }
         body,html{
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         }
         .nopm{
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         }
        #Menu ul{
          padding:0;
         margin:0;



         }
        #Menu li{
         list-style:none;
         float:left;
         padding:1em .3em;
         float:left;
         margin:2em 0;

         }
         #Menu a{

           text-decoration:none;
           font-family: Rockwell,Courier Bold,Courier,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif; 
        font-size: 24px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 28px;
        color:#fff;
        margin:1em .5em;
        padding:10px;
        border:2px solid #fff;

         }
         a:hover{ 

          border:4px solid #FFD700;
            -webkit-transition-delay: 2s; /* Safari */
        transition-delay: 2s;
         }
           @media (max-width:420px){

        li{

            width:100%;
      text-align:center;

        }
          img{
       display:block;
       width:90px;
       height:90px;
       margin:0 auto;
      }
      }
    h1,h3{color:#fff;
        text-align:center;

        }
        #Slogan
    {
    padding:2em 0;
    }
    #SignUpWrapper{
    width:100%;
     text-align: center;
    display:block;
    }
    form{

    width:100%;
    }
    input[type="text"],[type="email"],[type="password"]{
    font-family: Rockwell,Courier Bold,Courier,Georgia,Times,Times New Roman,serif; 
        font-size: 19px;
        font-style: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        line-height: 25px;
        color:#000 !important;
    padding:.5em;
    width:100%;

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="Banner">
<div id="Menu">
<div class="row nopm">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-2">
</div>
 <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
   <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/xpon69.png" />
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-5 col-sm-7">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-1">
</div>
</div>

</div>
<div id="Slogan">
<div class="row nopm">
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">

<h1>
Welcome to Meet Up Place
</h1>
<h3>
SignUp to create your own events
</h3>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-xs-12">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="SignUp">
<div class="row nopm">
<div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
<div id="SignUpWrapper">
                    <form  autocomplete="on">
                        <div class="InputWrapper"> 
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <label for="fName" style="    display: block;text-align:center;">First Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                 <input class="form-control" id="fName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"   >
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="InputWrapper"> 
                            <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
                            </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="lName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="InputWrapper"> 
                              <div class="input-group">
                            <label for="lName">E-Mail</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                            <input id="lName" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail" />
                                </div>
                        </div>


                    </form>
                </div>

</div>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
</div>
    </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Care to reduce the demo down to a reasonable size?

Comment: @Paulie_D I dont know if some other piece of code is overriding it or something .that is the reason why I dumped the entire code.Its nothing complicated.I have viewed more messy things here and have helped people with it.I have reduced it css and purely relevant html things.Even the text align center given as inline is not applying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `display: inline-block;` and remove `width: 100%;` on the `form` and it works.

[See it here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZxxYq)

If you want to center the inner content, try this :

```
.input-group { display: block !important; }
.form-control, input[type="text"], [type="email"], [type="password"] { text-align : center !important;}
```

I use `!important` because the style is in the HTML panel instead of the CSS one.

Your inline style **is applied** :

[image]

Comment: Bro here even inline code is not working so what is the reason for that inline code is supposed to work right since it is given higher preference ?

Comment: Check this  : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZxxYq 
I use the CSS panel so I was forced to put `!important` to make it works. Otherwise, it take the style which is in the HTML panel, between `<style></style>`

Comment: Okay but whats wrong with what I did why did the inline style did not apply

Comment: I've made a screenshot to show you that your inline style is applied.

Comment: yes but inline style was showing applied but it was not centering text.

Comment: yes I noticed that I was about to ask you about that okay .I am a bit rusty back to coding after 8 months.Thanks though.accepted  as anwer

Comment: Because it wasn't suffisant to do the centering. To center this element, he must be `inline-block`, not `block`. And the `text-align: center;` must be on the parent with `display: block` on the parent

Comment: .I dont know why but I applied it the parent and it didnt work.Did you mean immediate parent or grand parent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109150/discussion-between-vincent-g-and-sachin-divakar).

Answer (score 4):

Add this in the CSS code to center all the forms lines:

```
    .input-group {
       margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

- This is to center the div

or

```
    .input-group {
       width: 100%;
    }
```

- This is to enlarge the div, so the text can be centered.

Comment: Francisco what is causing  override of inline text-align:center statement.Upvote for it gives solution will accept as answer if you explain to me why my code was not working.

Comment: Yes exactly I was about to ask that

Comment: Sachin because of the width of the divs .input-group (The same size of the text so it can't be centered). You can set .input-group width:100% too and it will works.

Marcos you are right.